# Php admin panel with users permissions

Tags: php

This is my first question here and I beleive the question is not exists already :) I searched but without succes.

Ok, I have a next problem. 
I need some idea how to do a users permissions in admin panel. 
I want to have a super admin, admin and operator.
Anyone of this wiil have different privileges.
Super admin wiil have all privileges, admin some and operators some but not all will have the same privileges. 
I need a back-end logic for this.
How to do that without many if statements so my code looks nice? 
I use a Smarty template engine and oop php writen by my own.
I wiil assign with Smarty privilege but what next? 
Can anyone give me idea or some example code?

Thanks!

Comment: what permissions would you like to give what level?

Comment: You could have user levels set as constants and then use if/else statements. It's actually a lot simpler than you'd think.

Comment: you may check phpadminpanel.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using MVC this is a relatively simple task. Create the different roles in a table called `permissions` and then another table called `user_permissions` which connects the `user_id` to the `permission_id`. Then create a function, maybe in a class called `user` called `has_role()`. That function accepts two arguments: permission alias and eventually a user id.

If you want to avoid calling functions in the view, you can in your controller save different variables, which are passed to the view, such as:

```
$isAdmin = $user->has_role('admin');
$isOperator = $user->has_role('operator');
```

If you're only displaying some content to admins, you could do something like this in your views:

```
<?php if($isAdmin): ?>

<p>Admin only content</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

However, if you're having admin-only pages, simply putting

```
if(! $this->user->has_role('role')) {
  header("Location: /index.php");
  die();
}
```

will do the trick. All of this is of course doable without the MVC-part, it however becomes way cleaner with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I thought about assign one variable like $level = $user->has_role($user_id); So I have a three if statements on page and include a diffferent html page, u think this is a good option? I dont worry about database just about code being organized on page with html.

Comment: @consigliere Sure. You could assign each permission an "access level", where super-admin might be highhest etc. It doesn't really do anything different, but if that's what you prefer - stick with it! :) To be able to separate regular users from admins and so on, these if-statements are required.

Comment: Just one more thing to ask :) I have more files, header.tpl, nav.tpl which holds navigation, and main content of page where is data from database. Example, operators could not see link to users in navigation but super admin can, so I will have one if in nav.tpl, and in main secion of page another if what file to inluce to show data, practically I will have a two if statements for one thing. Is this good or bad? If is bad how I can avoid this but to keep logic with more tpls files being included in one. I just worry about speed and execution time.

Comment: @consigliere Well, you should always try to avoid duplicate code -- however, in some cases it's hard to avoid without making a major designing edit. In this case, the only possible way to avoid multiple if's here would be to have all admin-content on one page and so on, which generally isn't an option. Don't worry about the execution time, a few if's wont make any real difference.

Comment: Oh, and by the way: if you believe that my answer (or somebody elses) was correct; please mark it as accepted. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: thanks man these answers is exactly what I needed to know ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could do this by splitting up your admin views (presumably each type of user gets a different UI experience) and then including the correct file based on the user's privileges?

Tbh, this is quite hard to answer without knowing the workings of your OOP framework as this will define how you fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Session {

    public static function init() {
        @session_start();
    }

    public static function set($key, $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($key) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
        return $_SESSION[$key];
        }
    }

    public static function destroy() {
        //unset($_SESSION);
        session_destroy();
    }

}
```

Later you set the role in your login php, $data['role'] you get from mysql:

```
   Session::init();
   Session::set('role', $data['role']);
```

And to check for role use for example:

```
    $role = Session::get('role');
    if ($role != 'owner') {
        Session::destroy();
        header('location: '.URL.'login');
        exit;
    }
```